# Is there a way to localize more languages in English?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, internationalization

I explain.

My app is localized in Italian and English. Is there a way to localize all the other languages (except italian) in english?
If my app will be downloaded by a guy in China for example, i want him to display my app in English.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are you developing for ios or osx?

Comment: So you should tag it [cocoa-touch] and [objective-c]. not xcode, as you don't want to translate that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be done by default, as long as English is your default language, when the application doesn't find a properties file for any other language it will default to English.

In this case it will default to English, for every language but Italian.

Comment: Oh, so if a french,a spanish or anyone else open the app, it's been displayed in english, right? If so, thanks for the answer. I thought i had to do some strange things with the code to internationalize my app

Comment: Okay, i tried it on my iPod by changing the language and it works. Thank you!